# Using Maven Profile when Running Eclipse Debugger

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

In my m2eclipse project I have a *context.xml* file that specified my database connection setup (e.g., driver, url, username, password). Instead of specifying the values for these attributes directly in the *context.xml* file itself, I instead created a Maven profile in my project's *pom.xml* file that defines the values for these attributes. For example:

```
. . .
<properties>
    <database.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</database.driverClassName>
    <database.user>admin</database.user>
    . . .
</properties>
. . .
```

and inside my *context.xml* file you see

```
. . .
driverClassName="${database.driverClassName}"
username="${database.user}"
. . .
```

What I'd like to know is how to get my profile to populate the *context.xml* file when running the debugger in Eclipse. Right now I can't do this and simply run Eclipse's debugger with the context.xml hard coded in with the values (i.e., I don't use a Maven profile). Can this be easily done with a Maven profile when running the Eclipse debugger? Maybe it can be done with the m2eclipse Eclipse plugin? I'm running this on Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/)?

Check out this screencast to see how web resource filtering works with profiles in m2e-wtp : http://goo.gl/RysBw

Note the [profile management UI](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/maven/maven-news-3.3.0.Beta1.html) comes from [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) and can be installed standalone.

Comment: Ooooh, I like it. So can this be an m2eclipse substitute?

Comment: m2e-wtp is an m2e subproject. It requires m2e to work (m2e is the eclipse.org version of the old m2eclipse). The profile management UI is an m2e extension.

m2e and m2e-wtp will be installed by default in the Java EE Kepler distribution.

Comment: Very interesting! I'm looking forward to the next Eclipse release.I uninstalled my old m2e and installed m2e-wtp. Works like a charm. With the old m2e I had to apply Eclipse facets, and that got a bit frustrating .Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with a simpler approach. I'm using Tomcat on my project. Can I still use the Profile Management UI even though it comes from JBoss Tools?

Comment: Yes,as explained in http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/maven/maven-news-3.3.0.Beta1.html#itemname1. JBoss Tools is actually a set of features/plugins you can select individually and install. 

It can be installed from the Eclipse Market Place or directly from the following p2 repository http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/kepler/

Just select the Maven Profiles Management features.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). It's done at compile time, not limited to debugging. If I'm correct you only need to add:

```
  ...
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  ...
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that could work for me. I'm only trying to set up my Development environment. And I don't mind having to go to the POM to change it to Production values before deploy. I have to do this anyway since the host server I'm paying for can't do it.